# Turn a tag field id into an instance of the tag model

Tags: entrymodel, tags

The add-on I'm using to import blogs has this to save tags to an entry:

`craft()->relations->saveRelations($tagFieldId, $entryRecord['elementId'], $tags);`

Where the first arg is the field id for the tag, the second is the entry, and the third is the tags.

I'm getting an error that says $tagFieldId needs to be an instance of the tag model:

> Argument 1 passed to Craft\RelationsService::saveRelations() must be
>   an instance of Craft\FieldModel,

Can I turn my little field ID into an instance of this? How do I get a fresh one, if not? Thanks for your help.

Any suggestions on approaches appreciated.

Also - would tag tagmodel but I'm a wee newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the FieldModel using the `$tagFieldId` variable, and then pass that model into the function as follows:

```php
$tagFieldRecord = FieldRecord::model()->findById($tagFieldId);

$tagFieldModel = FieldModel::populateModel($tagFieldRecord);

craft()->relations->saveRelations($tagFieldModel, $entryRecord['elementId'], $tags);
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben - I'm getting an error from your first line: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Craft\FieldModel::model() in /the/file/..

Comment: just fixed the typo, try again

Comment: That did it! Please stay tuned for my next question - which may be the exact same for Arguement 2..

Comment: in theory it should follow the same principle as the code above...

Comment: All of this involves big structures that I've never seen before so I need more experience to grasp these patterns.